# Входная строка имела неверный формат double value

Tags: c#

Имею сайт с БД. При выгрузке таблицы в Эксель выводится ошибка

> Входная строка имела неверный формат

```
if (ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("," , ".") != "") // Строка 6188
{ // Строка 6189
    double value = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace(",", "."), NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); // Строка 6190
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = value; // Строка 6191
} // Строка 6192
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Проблема решена кодом:

```
if (double.TryParse(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Trim(), out doubleValue))
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = doubleValue;
                        }
                        else xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = null;
                    }
```

Comment: а в ячейке точно есть значение? ошибка может возникать при конвертации если в ячейке нет значения, либо если данные в этой ячейке невозможно конвертировать

Comment: за пробел может ведь принять за значение? А какие данные не конвертируемы?

Comment: ну если в ячейке есть пробел - то будет ошибка конвертации) что бы не было проблем с конвертацией в doouble, вам нужно иметь там только число, разделитель должен быть запятой а не точкой. И также что бы убрать пробелы, можете использовать `.Trim()`. Для проверки ячейки на пустоту можете использовать метод `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell)`.

Comment: Есть ячейки у которых имеется спереди по 8 пробелов, это он и имеет виду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала вам нужно проверить ячейку на пустоту, это делается с помощью метода `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. После, если строка не null и не содержит пробелы, вам необходимо считать значение с нее и убрать все лишние пробелы. Также необходимо заменить "Точку" в числе на "Запятую" и после уже конвертировать полученное значение в double. Вот пример с вашим кодом:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString())) // Если строка не пустая и не состоит только из пробелов
{
    // Считываем значение из ячейки, заменяем точку на запятую и убираем лишние пробелы
    var cellValue = ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace(".", ",").Trim();
    // Конвертируем в double
    double value = Convert.ToDouble(cellValue, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = value;
}
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке компилятора: CS0128: В этой области действия уже определена локальная переменная с именем "value"
double value = Convert.ToDouble(value, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo); вместо value "razdel"?

Comment: @macrosofaq а, так 2 переменные с одинаковым названием. Просто задайте другое название переменной где происходит считывание значения из ячейки, например cellValue. Исправил

Comment: Не помогает, все равно выходит ошибка.

Comment: @macrosofaq какая ошибка?

Comment: "Входная строка имела неверный формат"

Comment: @macrosofaq А вы смотрели какое значение находится в ячейке в которой выскакивает данная ошибка?

Comment: В столбце razdel только цифры от 1 до 5

Comment: @macrosofaq вы смотрели на какой строке возникает ошибка? В начале документа? Может где то в середине или в конце? Хоть какие либо значения обрабатываются или нет? Может у вас в столбце есть заголовок и вы его не пропустили и начинаете пытаться заголовок конвертировать в doouble и возникает ошибка? Посмотрите в какой строке возникает ошибка. Умеете пользоваться дебагером?

Comment: В отладке  -- NumberFormatInfo.InvarioantInfo - {System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo} - System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo / cellvalue - "X" - string / this - {ASP.webforms_content_ascx} - Control_content{ASP.webforms_content_ascx} /  value - 0 - double

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в точке, которую вы ставите вместо запятой.

Как я понимаю, это для того чтобы понять, входная строка является ли числом типа double.

Думаю целесообразнее использовать `double.TryParse()`.

1. Это вас избавит от выброса исключения при конвертировании
2. Это гарантирует выполнение кода в случае, если входная строка действительно число.
3. Вы всегда можете использовать блок `else`

```
if(double.TryParse(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Trim(), out double value))
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = value; 
}
else
{
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = string.Empty; // к примеру
}
```

Подробнее о методе `double.TryParse()` можете почитать тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: в if переменная value еще не указано. А так проверю

Comment: Она объявляется прямо в `if`. Пожалуйста прочитайте https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Спасибо помогло if (double.TryParse(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Trim(), out doubleValue))
                            {
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = doubleValue;
                            }
                            else xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = null;
                        }